# Write is faster than read on x86?

Tags: c, performance, x86, intel

I observe some very weird performance for read and write access on Intel machine.

I wrote a C program that allocate an array first. The code of the program is at [1] ; You can compile it by running Make. (I don't use any compiling optimization.)

The sequence of the operations of the program is as follows:

```
allocate a char array;
init each element of array to be 1;
use clflush to flush the whole array from cache;
read each cache line of the array by using tmp = array[i];
(Do simple calculation after reading each cache line)
use clflush to flush the whole array from cache;
write each cache line of the array by using array[i] = tmp;
(Do the same simple calculation after reading each cache line)
```

I run the program on Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz (Haswell arch.) with turbo boost disabled.

The command I used to run the program is:
sudo ./rw-latency-test-compute 5210 10 1

I got the read latency for the whole array is 6670us, while the write latency for the whole array is 3518us.

**The interesting part is**
If I don't do any computation after I read/write a cache line, the read latency for the whole array is 2175us, while the write latency for the whole array is 3687us.

So doing computation seems speed up the execution... :-(

Do you have any suggestion/explanation on this weird performance?

The whole assembly code of the program can be found at [2].

The assembly code of the inner loop is as follows:

```
0000000000400898 <read_array>:
  400898:   55                      push   %rbp
  400899:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40089c:   53                      push   %rbx
  40089d:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  4008a1:   48 89 7d d8             mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
  4008a5:   48 89 75 d0             mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
  4008a9:   c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
  4008b0:   c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
  4008b7:   eb 58                   jmp    400911 <read_array+0x79>
  4008b9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4008be:   e8 38 ff ff ff          callq  4007fb <sw_barrier>
  4008c3:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
  4008c6:   48 98                   cltq   
  4008c8:   48 03 45 d8             add    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
  4008cc:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
  4008cf:   88 45 ef                mov    %al,-0x11(%rbp)
  4008d2:   0f be 45 ef             movsbl -0x11(%rbp),%eax
  4008d6:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  4008d8:   03 4d e8                add    -0x18(%rbp),%ecx
  4008db:   ba 01 80 00 80          mov    $0x80008001,%edx
  4008e0:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  4008e2:   f7 ea                   imul   %edx
  4008e4:   8d 04 0a                lea    (%rdx,%rcx,1),%eax
  4008e7:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  4008e9:   c1 fa 0f                sar    $0xf,%edx
  4008ec:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  4008ee:   c1 f8 1f                sar    $0x1f,%eax
  4008f1:   89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
  4008f3:   29 c3                   sub    %eax,%ebx
  4008f5:   89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
  4008f7:   89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%rbp)
  4008fa:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  4008fd:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  4008ff:   c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
  400902:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
  400904:   89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
  400906:   29 c2                   sub    %eax,%edx
  400908:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  40090a:   89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%rbp)
  40090d:   83 45 e4 40             addl   $0x40,-0x1c(%rbp)
  400911:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
  400914:   48 98                   cltq   
  400916:   48 3b 45 d0             cmp    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  40091a:   7c 9d                   jl     4008b9 <read_array+0x21>
  40091c:   b8 e1 0f 40 00          mov    $0x400fe1,%eax
  400921:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  400924:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  400926:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400929:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40092e:   e8 3d fd ff ff          callq  400670 <printf@plt>
  400933:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  400937:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  400938:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400939:   c3                      retq   

000000000040093a <write_array>:
  40093a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40093b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40093e:   53                      push   %rbx
  40093f:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  400943:   48 89 7d d8             mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
  400947:   48 89 75 d0             mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
  40094b:   c6 45 ef 01             movb   $0x1,-0x11(%rbp)
  40094f:   c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
  400956:   c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
  40095d:   eb 63                   jmp    4009c2 <write_array+0x88>
  40095f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400964:   e8 92 fe ff ff          callq  4007fb <sw_barrier>
  400969:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
  40096c:   48 98                   cltq   
  40096e:   48 03 45 d8             add    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
  400972:   0f b6 55 ef             movzbl -0x11(%rbp),%edx
  400976:   88 10                   mov    %dl,(%rax)
  400978:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
  40097b:   48 98                   cltq   
  40097d:   48 03 45 d8             add    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
  400981:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%rax),%eax
  400984:   0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
  400987:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  400989:   03 4d e8                add    -0x18(%rbp),%ecx
  40098c:   ba 01 80 00 80          mov    $0x80008001,%edx
  400991:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  400993:   f7 ea                   imul   %edx
  400995:   8d 04 0a                lea    (%rdx,%rcx,1),%eax
  400998:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  40099a:   c1 fa 0f                sar    $0xf,%edx
  40099d:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  40099f:   c1 f8 1f                sar    $0x1f,%eax
  4009a2:   89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
  4009a4:   29 c3                   sub    %eax,%ebx
  4009a6:   89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
  4009a8:   89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%rbp)
  4009ab:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  4009ae:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  4009b0:   c1 e0 10                shl    $0x10,%eax
  4009b3:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
  4009b5:   89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
  4009b7:   29 c2                   sub    %eax,%edx
  4009b9:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  4009bb:   89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%rbp)
  4009be:   83 45 e4 40             addl   $0x40,-0x1c(%rbp)
  4009c2:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
  4009c5:   48 98                   cltq   
  4009c7:   48 3b 45 d0             cmp    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  4009cb:   7c 92                   jl     40095f <write_array+0x25>
  4009cd:   b8 ee 0f 40 00          mov    $0x400fee,%eax
  4009d2:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  4009d5:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  4009d7:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4009da:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4009df:   e8 8c fc ff ff          callq  400670 <printf@plt>
  4009e4:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  4009e8:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4009e9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4009ea:   c3                      retq
```

[1]https://github.com/PennPanda/rw-latency-test/blob/master/rw-latency-test-compute.c

[2] https://github.com/PennPanda/rw-latency-test/blob/2da88f1cccba40aba155317567199028b28bd250/rw-latency-test-compute.asm

Comment: You have not posted enough information for a definite answer, but I'd point out that your writes are probably pure sinks, meaning they can easily be buffered. Reads, in contrast, will stall the program is they have dependencies.

Comment: @EOF, could you please let me know what other information are necessary? I didn't post the whole program here but put it to github so that it won't be so messy...

Comment: Well, since you're asking about x86 specifically, I'd like to see the assembly-code for the inner loop of your testcases. Also, your timings have suspiciously many significant digits. How many runs did you time, what kind of mean, median results did you get, what kind of variance?

Comment: If your compiler is clever enough, it could avoid performing any of the array writes in function `write_array()`, as the values written are never used.  It would be less likely to do so if that function were in a separate translation unit, but some compilers are clever and aggressive enough at optimization to not be stopped by mere translation unit boundaries.

Comment: @EOF, I have added the objdump -S result from the binary. I also committed the whole assembly file to the github: https://github.com/PennPanda/rw-latency-test/blob/2da88f1cccba40aba155317567199028b28bd250/rw-latency-test-compute.asm

Comment: You could also try compiling with optimization disabled.  I'm inclined to think that the resulting program would be both slower and more consistent.

Comment: @MikeXu: I'd have preferred the output of `gcc -S`, since that is far more human-readable. Also, I in contrast to John, I'd prefer it if the compiler were set to a higher optimization level. `-O3` would produce readable code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I used gcc -O0 to compile the C program. Is there any other steps I should do to disable the optimization in compiling?

Comment: `gcc -O0` should be sufficient to disable all compile-time optimizations.

Comment: @EOF,  thank you very much for your suggestion! the result of gcc -S source_code is at https://github.com/PennPanda/rw-latency-test/blob/master/rw-latency-test-compute.s#L186

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write is faster than read because if you read from RAM and use the value (that is, you don't just read and discard), the processor has to stall for the read at the point the value is used. However, write proceeds asynchronously and never stalls.

Comment: However, I do flush the cache first; It means that when I write an array item, the Intel (write-allocate) cache will first allocate a cache line for the item (by loading it to cache) and then write it to the cache. In addition, the calculation will use the result in the array instead of the tmp value, which means, IMHO, the calculation has to wait for the value in the array to be ready. Isn't it?

Comment: @MikeXu: See store-load forwarding, which is exactly what is happening in your `write_array()`.

Comment: @EOF, I got the store-load forwarding now. Thank you very much for your suggestion! :-) BTW, may I ask a quick question? How did you tell the write_array() have the store-load forwarding issue, from the C source code or from the assembly code?

Comment: @MikeXu: Well, reading unoptimized assembly is a chore, so I had a look at the C-code. I then had a look at the assembly to confirm that the compiler emitted a load from the same location it had just stored to. This is a prime candidate for store-load forwarding.